# Calculating moving averages efficiently on big datasets in Python 2.7

Tags: python, statistics, moving-average, data-science

I am learning to calculate a moving average on a big dataset with more than two variables in Python. Here I’m having Date, companyID and PageViews:

```
    Date        CompanyID   PageViews
    01/01/2016     023        420       
    02/01/2016     023        362       
    03/01/2016     023        214       
    …               …          …        
    05/06/2016     311        54        
    06/06/2016     311        35        
    07/06/2016     311        69        
    …              …           …        
    04/03/2016     465        49        
    05/03/2016     465        17        
    …              …          …
```

I want to calculate 2 days moving averages for each company and date along the file and store the result as a new variable Avg2. The output should look like this:

```
    Date        CompanyID   PageViews      Avg2
    01/01/2016      023        420          NA
    02/01/2016      023        362         391  
    03/01/2016      023        214         288
    …                …          …           …   
    05/06/2016      311        54           NA
    06/06/2016      311        35          44.5
    07/06/2016      311        69          52
    …                …          …           …   
    04/03/2016      465        49           NA
    05/03/2016      465        17          33
    …                …          …           …
```

How would I do that efficiently without manually calculating it per each company? (I have 500 unique companies).

I tried to do this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../DataSet.csv', sep=',')
    df['Avg2'] = pd.rolling_mean(df.PageViews, window=2)
```

But it ignores CompanyID.

Comment: Where did you get stuck with your python code?

Comment: I would suggest indexing first by company and then by date first, then running the moving average algorith on every company

Comment: What do you mean by _"without manually calculating it per each company?"_

Comment: @Prajwal, I meant I could filter data per company and caltulate moving averages separately per company, but having 500 unique companies it would take ages to do so. I haven't used Python before, so I really don't know the tricks how to do it efficiently on the entire dataset.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I added what I've done. However, that code ignores CompanyIDs and I'm getting inappropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a 30-day moving average, keep the sum of the first 30 days. Then for each subsequent day, subtract the first day and add the subsequent day. You'll get each moving average in one subtraction, one addition, and one division (as opposed to 30 additions and one division).

If you want to slice out one company from the array, Python has a lot of ways to do this.